# VBA open workbook attached to outlook template

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, email-attachments

Is there any way that one can open a workbook attached to an email template, edit, and save it prior to sending the message?  I've created the mailitem object using `Set Mesg = OutlookAp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Template.oft")` and I can see the attachment, but I can't see a way to open it thus far.  If anyone has suggestions, or knows that this simply can't be done, I'm all ears.

Looks like I may have to save and edit the file prior to sending...  Still open to ideas, but it looks like it simply isn't possible to open the attachment through VBA

Comment: Have you had a chance to try my suggestion below?

Comment: Yes, I did, and I selected it as the correct answer.  Technically though I wanted to simply grab the attatchment object and open /  edit it in the current instance of excel without having to save it to a temp folder, etc.  It doesn't seem like the first is possible, so I did end up using a variation of this method.

Comment: This answer should be opening the file in the current instance of Excel. Is it not? As for the temporary folder... the answer below doesn't use a temporary folder, but it does require to save and open the file from a known location.  It *may* be possible to use a true temporary folder, if you can replicate the double-click action (that would open the file from a temp folder) but that would need to be done some other way. the Attachment object only supports two methods (`.Delete` and `.SaveAsFile`), I was looking for something like `OLEFormat.DoVerb` but that doesn't seem to be an option here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are automating Outlook *from* Excel.  This solution may work for you, but as you note it does rely on saving the attachment and re-attaching the manipulated version of the file.  Assuming you can write the code which will "edit" the Workbook attachment, this should work for you.

```
Sub TestOutlookTemplate()

Dim MyOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim MyMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim att As Outlook.Attachment
Dim templatePath As String
Dim tempFileName As String
Dim attWorkbook As Workbook


templatePath = "C:\users\david_zemens\desktop\Untitled.oft"
tempFileName = "C:\users\david_zemens\desktop\tempexcelfile.xlsx"

Set MyOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set MyMail = MyOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate(templatePath)
    MyMail.Display

    For Each att In MyMail.Attachments
        If att.DisplayName Like "*.xls*" Then
            att.SaveAsFile tempFileName

            'Now that you have saved the file, delete the attachment
            att.Delete

            'Open the file
            Set attWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(tempFileName)

            'Perform manipulation on the file
            attWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = "Sheet ONE"

            'Save fhe file
            attWorkbook.Save

            'Close the file
            attWorkbook.Close

            MyMail.Attachments.Add tempFileName
        End If
    Next


'Send your mail (make sure you have added a recipient
MyMail.Send

Set attWorkbook = Nothing
Set MyMail = Nothing
Set MyOutlook = Nothing


End Sub
```